# Where is the log file when I'm using svn+ssh?

Tags: svn, ssh

Title is pretty much the question.  I have a post-commit that has taken me ages to get permissions working correctly.

I can run it manually and it works, however, when I actually make a commit (as the same user that I know works manually) nothing happens.

Will anything be logged anywhere? Or can I set up pseudo-logging or something?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try debugging the hook per the subversion directions?

[Why aren't my repository hooks working?](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#hook-debugging)

> They're supposed to invoke external programs, but the invocations never seem to happen.
>
> Before Subversion calls a hook script, it removes all variables -- including $PATH on Unix, and %PATH% on Windows -- from the environment. Therefore, your script can only run another program if you spell out that program's absolute name.
>
> Debugging tips:
>
> If you're using Linux or Unix, try running the script "by hand", by following these steps:
>
> 1. Use "su", "sudo", or something similar, to become the user who normally would run the script. This might be httpd or www-data, for example, if you're using Apache; it might be a user like svn if you're running svnserve and a special Subversion user exists. This will make clear any permissions problems that the script might have.
> 2. Invoke the script with an empty environment by using the "env" program. Here's an example for the post-commit hook:
>
>    ```
>          $ env - ./post-commit /var/lib/svn-repos 1234
>    ```
>
> Note the first argument to "env" is a dash; that's what ensures the environment is empty.
>      3. Check your console for errors.

Comment: If I run over ssh, i.e. svn+ssh it will be invoked by the user sshing right?

Comment: Correct. If you have user@ in the URL, it will be "user".

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
svn help log
```

Unless you're talking about some other kind of logging?

Comment: I don't think that really helps, I need some kind of indication as to why my post-commit is failing, all that seems to show is the revisions that have worked when I've run the post-commit script manually.

Comment: Hrm try your ssh logs then which on a unix/linux system would be in /var/log